# Execution of extended Xbase interpreter leads to runtime exception

Tags: interpreter, xtext, xtend, xbase

I am currently writing an interpreter for an Xtext language that extends Xbase.

To do so I am inheriting from XbaseInterpreter, adding my own `run` method and override the dispatch method `doEvaluateProgram` with my new abstract concepts.

The problem arises in the interpretation of the `CondStmt`. Its semantics is to evaluate the exp `XExpression` and call the stmts statements only if the evaluation of exp returns true.

When the interpreter is called (let's say from the test case below), the evaluation of the exp `XExpression` fails with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Segment cannot be null` exception.

Both sides of the `==` statement, e.g. `_inPort` and `inSide` are supposed to be variables defined in the interpretation context using the `newValue` method.

I'm guessing the runtime error has something to do with a failure to identify the type and/or the value of the variables, but I can't figure out how to fix this issues.

PS: The full stack trace below.

**The grammar:**

```
grammar MyLang with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate mylang "http://MyLang"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase

// ...

CondStmt returns xbase::XExpression:
    {CondStmt} "cond" "(" exp=XExpression "," stmts+=Stmt* ")";

// ...
```

**The interpreter**

```
class MyLangInterpreter extends XbaseInterpreter {

    val indicator = CancelIndicator.NullImpl

    def run(MyProgram program) {
        // ...
        val context = this.createContext
        // ...
        val newContext = context.fork
        newContext.newValue(QualifiedName.create("_inPort"), "something"))
        myElement.doEvaluate(newContext, indicator)
       // ...
    }

    def dispatch doEvaluateProgram(MyElem elem, IEvaluationContext context, CancelIndicator indicator) {
        // ...
    }

    def dispatch doEvaluateProgram(CondStmt condStmt, IEvaluationContext context, CancelIndicator indicator) {
        val exp = this.evaluate(condStmt.exp, context, indicator)

        if (Boolean.TRUE == exp) {
            condStmt.stmts.map [
                this.internalEvaluate(it, context, indicator)
            ].last
        }
    } 
}
```

**The test case**

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(GpflInjectorProvider)
class GpflInterpreterTest {

    @Inject private extension ParseHelper<Program> parseHelper
    @Inject private extension GpflInterpreter

    @Test
    def test1() {
        val program = '''
            // ...
            cond(_inPort == inSide, 
              // ...
            )
            // ....
        '''.parse

        val res = program.run

        // ...
    }
}
```

**The stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Segment cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.xtext.naming.QualifiedName.create(QualifiedName.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter._invokeFeature(XbaseInterpreter.java:1008)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter.invokeFeature(XbaseInterpreter.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter._doEvaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter._doEvaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:864)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter.doEvaluate(GpflInterpreter.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter.internalEvaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter._doEvaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:900)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter.doEvaluate(GpflInterpreter.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter.internalEvaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.interpreter.impl.XbaseInterpreter.evaluate(XbaseInterpreter.java:189)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter._doEvaluate(GpflInterpreter.java:314)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter.doEvaluate(GpflInterpreter.java:430)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter.lambda$3(GpflInterpreter.java:263)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter$$Lambda$13/974320615.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at mylang.MyLangInterpreter.run(GpflInterpreter.java:265)
    at fr.mleduc.gpfl.tests.MyLangInterpreterTest.test1(GpflInterpreterTest.java:113)
...
```

Comment: did you debug if the feature is a proxy?

Comment: ```public /* @Nullable */ String getSimpleName(JvmIdentifiableElement element) {
  if (element == null || element.eIsProxy()) {
   return null;
  }```

Comment: and if yes which feature is the proxy? ==

Comment: besides this i wont use parse helper to do the parsing cause it may behave wired in combination with xbase

Comment: The feature is indeed a proxy of type JvmVoidImplCustom (toString: JvmVoid:  (eProxyURI: __synthetic0.mylang#|9)). By consequence, your implementation of getSimpleName return null when executed with this feature. Also, how can I avoid the use of the parse helper?

Comment: posted you a snippet. i dont see any toString in your sample code

Comment: JvmVoid: (eProxyURI: __synthetic0.mylang#|9) is the result of calling the toString method on the feature of the XFeatureCall evaluated ("_inPort" in my test).

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of loading the model without parsehelper

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(DomainmodelInjectorProvider)
class DullyTest{

    @Inject Provider<XtextResourceSet> rsp
    @Inject ValidationTestHelper helper

    @Test
    def void xxxxx() {
        val rs = rsp.get
        rs.classpathURIContext = DullyTest
        val r = rs.createResource(URI.createURI("dummy.dmodel"))
        val text = '''
        entity Person {
            op xxxx() {
                1==1
            }
        }
        '''
        r.load(new StringInputStream(text), null)
        helper.assertNoIssues(r)
        val m = r.contents.head as DomainModel
```

Comment: Thanks. This example is working properly but regarding my runtime exception issue, I'm obtaining the same result with both parsing methods.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example

Comment: https://github.com/manuelleduc/gpfl is the "real world" project with the issue. Run https://github.com/manuelleduc/gpfl/blob/master/fr.mleduc.gpfl.tests/src/fr/mleduc/gpfl/tests/GpflInterpreterTest.xtend to reproduce the issue

Comment: you did not implement ITypeComputer nor did you assign your expressions to a body or initializer

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it. Currently, my only source of examples if the TortoiseShell language of the seven languages repository (https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext/tree/master/languages/org.xtext.tortoiseshell). And it does not seem to use ITypeComputer. Is there any resource I could read to gain some insights on how to use it?